# Why does clang create these implicit methods when a class contains a virtual method?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, clang, libtooling

I'm working on a tool based on clang's AST, and I'm curious to know why clang works this way.

Here's my input.  I have a very simple class that is defined like this:

```
class Foo {
    int foo();
};
```

Then in my RecursiveASTVisitor, I have code that looks like this:

```
bool MyASTVisitor::VisitCXXRecordDecl(clang::CXXRecordDecl *D) {
    for (auto const & method : D->methods()) {
        llvm::outs() << method->getQualifiedNameAsString() << "(";
        for (auto const & param : method->params())
            llvm::outs() << param->getType().getAsString() << ", ";
        llvm::outs() << ")";
        if (method->isImplicit())
            llvm::outs() << " [implicit]";
        llvm::outs() << "\n";
    }
    return true;
}
```

All this does is spit out the list of methods defined in all the classes that are visited.  The output for this is as we'd expect:

```
Foo::foo()
```

Now, let's make a small change to our Foo class.  Let's make the foo() method virtual:

```
class Foo {
    virtual int foo();
};
```

Now my output changes:

```
Foo::foo()
Foo::operator=(const class Foo &, ) [implicit]
Foo::~Foo() [implicit]
```

My question is, why does adding a virtual method to a class cause clang to create an implicit assignment operator and destructor?  If I add --std=c++11, it creates an implicit move-assignment operator as well.  Is this an implementation detail of clang, or is it part of the C++ standard?

Comment: A way to copy the vtable and destroy it ?

Comment: BTW, standard doesn't make rules on resulting AST.

Comment: Note that every class has a destructor. C++ as a language is not immediately connected with a compiler's AST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I should just read the clang source code.  `SemaDeclCXX.cpp` has a method called `Sema::AddImplicitlyDeclaredMembersToClass`.  There's a comment about why it declares the implicit copy assignment:

```
if (!ClassDecl->hasUserDeclaredCopyAssignment()) {
  ++ASTContext::NumImplicitCopyAssignmentOperators;

  // If we have a dynamic class, then the copy assignment operator may be
  // virtual, so we have to declare it immediately. This ensures that, e.g.,
  // it shows up in the right place in the vtable and that we diagnose
  // problems with the implicit exception specification.
  if (ClassDecl->isDynamicClass() ||
      ClassDecl->needsOverloadResolutionForCopyAssignment())
    DeclareImplicitCopyAssignment(ClassDecl);
}
```

So it does this in order to ensure that the implicitly defined methods, that may be virtual, end up in the right place in the vtable.